# Was there any time in non-recent history where it was fashionable to wear ripped clothes?

Tags: clothing, fashion

For around past 30 years it's popular to wear [ripped jeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripped_jeans). Was there anything similar in history, when ripped or otherwise heavily worn clothes were popular and considered fashionable?

Comment: 30 years, LOL, you must be a young man. Just 20 years ago everyone in white collar work in the US had to wear a suit to work, imagine that. I remember when "casual Fridays" were invented around 1995. Even faded jeans did not appear until around 2000. When the Gap started selling faded jeans I thought that was pretty funny.

Comment: @TylerDurden Some of us still wear suits to work.

Comment: @franklin That is so passe, didn't you know you are supposed to wear ripped jeans?

Comment: Popular among whom?  The Elizabethans wore slashed/pinked doublets &c, but that was more to let underlayers show through as a statement of wealth: "I'm rich enough to wear two layers of expensive cloth!"

Comment: @jamesqf i think that would qualify as an answer, because most of the "ripped" jeans are now actually sold that way, and so it has become the same thing, i bought designer clothes look you can tell because their ripped. write that up with some evidence/pics and that should probably be the right answer.

Comment: @Tyler Durden: Not sure if you're serious, but that just ain't so.  Been in a "white collar" field (programming/softwear engineering) since the mid-80s, have never worn a suit to work, and can't offhand recall anyone outside upper management (or sometimes new hires from abroad, until they caught on to the local culture) who did.  In fact, 'suit' was (and maybe still is) used as an expression of contempt.

Comment: @jamesqf Maybe you worked in California or something. I worked at over 20 companies in New York and Boston from 1988 to 1995 as a contractor and every single one required a suit and tie, including Houghton-Mifflin, Boston University, Prudential Insurance, etc. White collar before about 1995 meant exactly that: a white dress shirt and a tie. Between 1995-1998 many companies adopted "casual Friday". Around 1998, the internet boom, tech companies started doing  casual attire every day. Maybe things were different in San Diego or something, but in the Northeast corridor, thats how it was.

Comment: @Tyler Durden: Sure, but you did say "in the US".  The Northeast corridor had/has many cultural differences from the rest of the country, especially the West where I worked.  Interesting anecdote: Company I worked for in the early '90s was one of the first to buy IBM's RISC workstations.  Didn't work, so first-level tech support came, wearing standard suits & ties.  No luck, so second-level came, fairly dressy casual.  That didn't help, so they called the top level: this hippie-looking guy in T-shirt & jeans, and the next day we were up & running.

Comment: In the USA, factory faded and ripped jeans started being fashionable in the later 1970s.

Comment: Ripped clothing became very popular in the US with the movie Flashdance in 1983. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/7c/Flashdanceposter.jpg/220px-Flashdanceposter.jpg

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Switzerland, and the Germanies, 1500s and 1600s in the form of the Landsknecht who were given a legal dispensation from the sumptuary (clothing) laws to be so fabulous.  There is [a contemporary recreation community](http://www.landsknechtguild.com/) who have some colour pictures of recreated clothes draped on people, and a wide variety of pictures online, including some colour prints from later.

[image: This image comes from the 4th edition of Meyers Konversationslexikon (1885–90). The copyrights have expired and this image is in the public domain.]

> From the Wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landsknecht
>
> Clothes
>
> What made the Landsknechte so conspicuous was their elaborate dress, which they adopted from the Swiss, but later took to even more dramatic excess. Maximilian I exempted them from the prevalent sumptuary laws as an acknowledgement of their "...short and brutish" lives. Doublets (German: Wams), deliberately slashed at the front, back and sleeves with shirts and other wear pulled through to form puffs of different-colored fabric, so-called puffed and slashed; particoloured hose (or Gesses); jerkins (German: Lederwams); ever-broader flat beret-type hats (German: Tellerbarrets) with tall feathers; and broad flat shoes, made them bodies of men that could not be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Jules-Amédée Barbey d'Aurevilly, in *Du Dandysme et de Georges Brummel* (*The Anatomy of Dandyism*, 1845) claims that French dandies of his day used to use a piece of broken glass to shave down the fabric of their coats until they were almost sheer, and might break through. If you want to believe him. I don't consider him very reliable, especially since a lined jacket isn't going to work like this.